# iteratively appending different dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, nested, iteration

I have an xml file with 2 different xml message types embedded in it.  I build a tree element list for each message type by searching for the elements of the first and then the second (do loop).  I want to group the resulting different dictionaries into one dictionary so that the elements remain separate.

**E.g.**

```
d1 = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
d2 = {'d': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0}
```

so that the final output is

```
dAll = {{d1}, {d2}}
```

It's not an update function because that groups `d1` and `d2` together and there isn't a append function for `dAll` as a dict object. How do I do this?

Comment: `{{d1}, {d2}}` - that's invalid (syntax). what are the keys?

Comment: The final result desired is: dAll = {{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'d': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0}}. Keys are explicit now.  Sorry.

Comment: I beg your pardon.  You are suggesting that dAll = [ d1, d2].  That will work.  But, as I iterate through the messages and build the element trees,  I check that d1 (or d2) does not already exist in the dAll list.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure, do that... or, if you don't care about order, you could use a `set`, but then you need an immutable (frozen) dict (more trouble)

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries contain *key-value pairs*.

You cannot put a dictionary as value alone in a dictionary. You need a key for the value.

Perhaps you want a `list`? Use `[d1, d2]`